# execute if the length of the array is greater than 1

Tags: javascript, arrays

If the length of the array is greater than 1 then i would like for the console to log the desired code however the console logs the else statement instead.

```
var hello = "Hello, ";
var arrayNames = [];

function greet(name){

if(name==null){
    console.log(hello + "my friend")
}

//Requirement UpperCase
for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    if(name[i]===name[i].toUpperCase()){
        console.log(hello.toUpperCase() + name[i].toUpperCase())

    }

}
//Requirement last element
arrayNames.push(name)

if(arrayNames.length>1){

    var lastElement = arrayNames.pop()
    console.log(hello + arrayNames + " and " + lastElement)
}


else{
    console.log(hello + arrayNames)
}


}

greet(["James", "Garry", "JOSHUA", "steven"])
```

Comment: Your array length is `1` - you have an array, that contains another array at the first index. `.concat` will merge 2 arrays together, that `push` just adding the entire array at the last index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing the whole array into another array as an element.

```
//Requirement last element
arrayNames.push(name) //[Array[4]]

//change this to 
Array.prototype.push.apply(arrayNames, name)

// if you want to use spread operator do this
arrayNames.push(...name)
```

Comment: Thanks @ Hitesh Kumar. This works however when i have only one name as an arguement without an array it throws an error TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

Comment: are you passing your name like this `greet('James')`?

Comment: yes, i would like for it work with array and without

Comment: then do this `arrayNames = arrayNames.concat(name)`

Comment: That worked for strings and arrays thanks. Also what if the greet parameter is null. I would like for the console to log that. At the moment it throws an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined. Sorry im new to this, would appreciate the help

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but you can do this `name = name|| ''`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136453/discussion-between-eyedfox1-and-hitesh-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing one item into arrayNames. It happens to be an array but it is ONE array, so arrayNames.length = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Error is [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) use to add one element to array.

You should use `concat`

```
arrayNames = arrayNames.concat(name)
```

instead

```
arrayName.push(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm more in the C# world than Javascript, but I think what you've got is a "type" problem.  You are calling the greet function with an array of strings.  When you push that into your arrayNames, arrayNames becomes an array of an array of strings - that is, each element of arrayNames is itself an array of strings, and there is only one of them because you are only calling greet once.

Instead, try changing `greet(["James", "Garry", "JOSHUA", "steven"])` to this and it should work (noting that James will not meet the if condition since he is the first):

```
greet("James")
greet("Garry")
greet("JOSHUA")
greet("steven")
```

Or you could get fancy and do a for or foreach loop.